# Preprocessor macro GCC: pasting x and x does not give a valid preprocessing token

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation, stringification

```
#define  PATH  "yagh/headers/"
#define  FILNAME  "includefile"


#define CONCAT(a__, b__) CONCAT_DO(a__, b__)
#define CONCAT_DO(a__, b__) a__##b__
#define CONCATTHREE(a__, b__, c__) CONCAT(CONCAT(a__, b__), c__)
#define STRINGIFY(a__) #a__


#include STRINGIFY(CONCATTHREE(PATH  ,FILNAME  ,.h));
```

This macro works fine in VS compiler but does not compile on GCC compiler:

> Error: error: pasting "/" and "includefile" does not give a valid preprocessing token

and for some include files it gives the error:

> Error: pasting "includefile" and "." does not give a valid preprocessing token

Comment: Concatenation with the `##` operator does not work with string literals such as `"foo"` in GCC. What exactly are you trying to do with this macro?

Comment: Did you ever find an acceptable answer to this problem?

Comment: Interesting.  I would expect both to give an error like `unable to find include file "CONCATTHREE(PATH  ,FILNAME  ,.h)"`, which is in fact what I see when I run your code through gcc...

Answer (score 2):

GCC is being a bit stricter in enforcing the C standard: see [Differences in Macro ## concatenation operator between Visual-C++ and gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206624/differences-in-macro-concatenation-operator-between-visual-c-and-gcc?rq=1) and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation.

You might try `#include STRINGIFY(PATH FILNAME.h)` (the lack of space between `FILNAME` and `.h` is important) -- that works for me with gcc 4.6.3.