# Problems with Delegate Template Metaprogramming

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-12.04, template-meta-programming

The below code was adapted by another programmer from [Yingle Jia's code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6840/Introduction-to-ACF-Another-C-Framework) and I'm having to port it to Linux. It compiles perfectly fine in VS2010, but when I try building in Ubuntu with gcc 4.6.3, it shows errors at

```
template <class R ACF_DELEGATE_COMMA ACF_DELEGATE_TEMPLATE_PARAMS>
class  Delegate<R (ACF_DELEGATE_TEMPLATE_ARGS)>
```

The error message being:

```
../../../mySDK-master/include/abc/DelegateTemplate.h:45:1: error: pasting "," and "class" does not give a valid preprocessing token
../../../mySDK-master/include/abc/DelegateTemplate.h:46:1: error: pasting "," and "T" does not give a valid preprocessing token
../../../mySDK-master/include/abc/DelegateTemplate.h:74:1: error: pasting "," and "a" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

lines 45 and 46 are the two lines of code of `DelegateTemplate.h` I've pasted above.

**Delegate.h**

```
// Copyright (C) 2004-2005 Yingle Jia
//
// Permission to copy, use, modify, sell and distribute this software is 
// granted provided this copyright notice appears in all copies. 
// This software is provided "as is" without express or implied warranty, 
// and with no claim as to its suitability for any purpose.
//
// AcfDelegate.h
//

#ifndef __Acf_Delegate__
#define __Acf_Delegate__

#ifndef __Acf_Corlib__
#include <stdexcept> // for std::runtime_error
#endif // #ifndef __Acf_Corlib__
#include <utility> // for std::pair

// Macros for template metaprogramming

#define ACF_JOIN(a, b)        ACF_DO_JOIN(a, b)
#define ACF_DO_JOIN(a, b)     ACF_DO_JOIN2(a, b)
#define ACF_DO_JOIN2(a, b)    a##b

#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_0(t)
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_1(t)    t##1
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_2(t)    t##1, ##t##2
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_3(t)    t##1, ##t##2, ##t##3
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_4(t)    t##1, ##t##2, ##t##3, ##t##4
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_5(t)    t##1, ##t##2, ##t##3, ##t##4, ##t##5
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_6(t)    t##1, ##t##2, ##t##3, ##t##4, ##t##5, ##t##6

#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2_0(t1, t2)
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2_1(t1, t2)   t1##1 t2##1
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2_2(t1, t2)   t1##1 t2##1, t1##2 t2##2
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2_3(t1, t2)   t1##1 t2##1, t1##2 t2##2, t1##3 t2##3
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2_4(t1, t2)   t1##1 t2##1, t1##2 t2##2, t1##3 t2##3, t1##4 t2##4
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2_5(t1, t2)   t1##1 t2##1, t1##2 t2##2, t1##3 t2##3, t1##4 t2##4, t1##5 t2##5
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2_6(t1, t2)   t1##1 t2##1, t1##2 t2##2, t1##3 t2##3, t1##4 t2##4, t1##5 t2##5, t1##6 t2##6

#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1(n, t)         ACF_JOIN(ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_, n) (t)
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2(n, t1, t2)    ACF_JOIN(ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2_, n) (t1, t2)

namespace CORE
{

#ifndef __Acf_Corlib__
class InvalidOperationException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    InvalidOperationException() : std::runtime_error("Invalidate operation")
    {
    }
};
#endif // #ifndef __Acf_Corlib__

template <class TSignature>
class  Delegate; // no body

} 

// Specializations

#define ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS   0 // Delegate<R ()>
#include "DelegateTemplate.h"
#undef ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS

#define ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS   1 // Delegate<R (T1)>
#include "DelegateTemplate.h"
#undef ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS

#define ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS   2 // Delegate<R (T1, T2)> 
#include "DelegateTemplate.h"
#undef ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS

#define ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS   3 // Delegate<R (T1, T2, T3)>
#include "DelegateTemplate.h"
#undef ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS

#define ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS   4 // Delegate<R (T1, T2, T3, T4)>
#include "DelegateTemplate.h"
#undef ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS

#define ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS   5 // Delegate<R (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5)>
#include "DelegateTemplate.h"
#undef ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS

#define ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS   6 // Delegate<R (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)>
#include "DelegateTemplate.h"
#undef ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS

#define N_INVOKE(DELEGATE,PARAMS) { if(DELEGATE) DELEGATE.Invoke PARAMS; }
#define N_EVENT_HANDLER(a) std::make_pair(this,&a);

#endif // #ifndef __Acf_Delegate__
```

**and a small part of DelegateTemplate.h**

```
// Copyright (C) 2004-2005 Yingle Jia
//
// Permission to copy, use, modify, sell and distribute this software is 
// granted provided this copyright notice appears in all copies. 
// This software is provided "as is" without express or implied warranty, 
// and with no claim as to its suitability for any purpose.
//
// AcfDelegateTemplate.h
//
// Note: this header is a header template and must NOT have multiple-inclusion
// protection.

#define ACF_DELEGATE_TEMPLATE_PARAMS    ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1(ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS, class T)
    // class T0, class T1, class T2, ...
#define ACF_DELEGATE_TEMPLATE_ARGS      ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1(ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS, T)
    // T0, T1, T2, ...
#define ACF_DELEGATE_FUNCTION_PARAMS    ACF_MAKE_PARAMS2(ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS, T, a)
    // T0 a0, T1 a1, T2 a2, ...
#define ACF_DELEGATE_FUNCTION_ARGS      ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1(ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS, a)
    // a0, a1, a2, ...

//// Comma if nonzero number of arguments 
#if ACF_DELEGATE_NUM_ARGS == 0
    #define ACF_DELEGATE_COMMA  
#else
    #define ACF_DELEGATE_COMMA  ,
#endif

namespace CORE
{

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// class Delegate<R (T1, T2, ..., TN)>

template <class R ACF_DELEGATE_COMMA ACF_DELEGATE_TEMPLATE_PARAMS>
class  Delegate<R (ACF_DELEGATE_TEMPLATE_ARGS)>
{
// Declarations
private:
    class DelegateImplBase
    {
    // Fields
    public:
        DelegateImplBase* Previous; // singly-linked list

    // Constructor/Destructor
    protected:
        DelegateImplBase() : Previous(NULL) { }
        DelegateImplBase(const DelegateImplBase& other) : Previous(NULL) { }
    public:
        virtual ~DelegateImplBase() { }

    // Methods
    public:
        virtual DelegateImplBase* Clone() const = 0;
        virtual R Invoke(ACF_DELEGATE_FUNCTION_PARAMS) const = 0;
    };
```

Is it because of a lack of Template Metaprogramming support in gcc? I checked for whether it would be because of variadic templates, but that's supposed to be fixed in gcc 4.3 itself. Would be grateful if you could help with solving this error.

Comment: There are no variadic templates here, just preprocessor hacks to try and work around the fact that C++ didn't have variadic templates. This sort of code is exactly why they were introduced.

Comment: Removing the `The token pasting operator ##` didn't help either. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1206687/453673. Nor did replacing it with a space.

Comment: Consider installing a newer GCC, like 4.8; it has quite good C++2011 support.

Comment: Thanks. The problem though, was because the previous programmer added some extra token pasting operators; as I've shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I went through [this page](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC18) and understood how the token pasting operator was supposed to be used:

Turns out there were some extra `##` operators which Visual Studio ignored, but gcc didn't.
The lines I changed were these:

```
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_0(t)
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_1(t)    t ## 1
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_2(t)    t ## 1,  t ## 2
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_3(t)    t ## 1,  t ## 2,  t ## 3
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_4(t)    t ## 1,  t ## 2,  t ## 3,  t ## 4
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_5(t)    t ## 1,  t ## 2,  t ## 3,  t ## 4,  t ## 5
#define ACF_MAKE_PARAMS1_6(t)    t ## 1,  t ## 2,  t ## 3,  t ## 4,  t ## 5,  t ## 6
```

The lines earlier had something like `##t##2` which was creating the error. I changed it to `t##2` and it worked! Glory Hallelujah! :-) So ends my ordeal with template metaprogramming.