# Microsoft C++ and g++ preprocessor behavior difference

Tags: c++, g++, preprocessor

I have such test program :

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"


#define ENTYPEDATA_STEP_3_D 3
#define ENTYPEDATA_STEP_10_2F 10
#define ENTYPEDATA_STEP_HEADER_4_D (4)
#define UINT unsigned int


#define SBUF_HEADER_INIT(n, data, m)\
 sprintf(cTmpTb,"%d",##m);\
 strcpy(cTmpTf,"%");\
 strcat(cTmpTf,cTmpTb);\
 strcat(cTmpTf,"d");\
 sprintf(TmpHeaderBuf,cTmpTf,data);\
 strcpy(this->m_pBufs##n,TmpHeaderBuf);

class m_test {
    private:
     char TmpHeaderBuf[ENTYPEDATA_STEP_HEADER_4_D+1];
     char cTmpTb[50];
     char cTmpTf[50];
     char TmpBuf[ENTYPEDATA_STEP_10_2F+1];

    char *m_pBufs0;
    char *m_pBufs5;

    public:
        m_test();
        ~m_test();
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    m_test l_test;
    return 0;
}


m_test::m_test(){
    m_pBufs0= new char[20];
    m_pBufs5= new char[20];

    SBUF_HEADER_INIT(5, (UINT)(ENTYPEDATA_STEP_3_D), ENTYPEDATA_STEP_HEADER_4_D)
}

m_test::~m_test(){
    delete m_pBufs0;
    delete m_pBufs5;
}
```

Under Microsoft Visual Studio C++ ver 6 this file compiling without any errors, but under g++ 7.4.0 i get some errors about my macro:

```
$g++ test_macro.cpp
test_macro.cpp:16:21: error: pasting "," and "ENTYPEDATA_STEP_HEADER_4_D" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  sprintf(cTmpTb,"%d",##m);\
                     ^
test_macro.cpp:51:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘SBUF_HEADER_INIT’
     SBUF_HEADER_INIT(5, (UINT)(ENTYPEDATA_STEP_3_D), ENTYPEDATA_STEP_HEADER_4_D)
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don`t understand how to fix it without full separation into some simple macros.
Please help.

UPD:
The macro

```
#define SBUF_HEADER_INIT(N, data, MD)\
 sprintf(cTmpTb,"%d",MD);\
 strcpy(cTmpTf,"%");\
 strcat(cTmpTf,cTmpTb);\
 strcat(cTmpTf,"d");\
 sprintf(TmpHeaderBuf,cTmpTf,data);\
 strcpy(this->m_pBufs##N,TmpHeaderBuf);
```

working perfect

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1206624/560648

Answer (score 3):

GCC is correct.

You wanted just `m`.

You're attempting to perform token concatenation where it does not make sense to do so.

Visual Studio 6 is permitting it anyway (as does VS 2019). Technically your approach has undefined behaviour so any outcome is actually "correct", but GCC's makes the most sense. Note that [Visual Studio's behaviour is undocumented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/token-pasting-operator-hash-hash?view=vs-2019) so I wouldn't even rely on it in that environment if I were tempted.

Comment: Just an FYI: VS 2019 seems to accept it too … It treats it as `(4)` which was rather surprising.

Comment: @ChrisMM: Figures!